# Psycog2 will not return any data

Tags: python, postgresql

I am learning to use PostgreSQL with Python. I am using the Psycog2 library to access a local database which has one record:

```
[postgres@<my-ip> ~]$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql
psql (16.0)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SELECT * FROM <table_name>;
      <timestamp>    |    <text>   | <number> 
---------------------+-------------+-------
 1999-01-08 04:05:06 | your_mother |    69
(1 row)
```

I wrote a class Db_Interactor (yeah, I know the name sucks) to manage all my data saving/accessing. On instantiation it creates a database connection (self.conn) which is closed upon deletion. The connection throws no errors and has no problems. The trouble is with when I actually try to get some data. I have a function within Db_Interactor which attempts to do this but it doesn't return correctly:

## Function:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from configparser import ConfigParser
import psycopg2

# NOTE: I got this config function from some tutorial I found

def config(filename='database.ini', section='postgresql'):
    # create a parser
    parser = ConfigParser()
    # read config file
    parser.read(filename)

    # get section, default to postgresql
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    return db

class Db_Interactor:

    def __init__(self):
        """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """
        self.conn = None
        try:
            # read connection parameters
            self.params = config()

            # connect to the PostgreSQL server
            print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
            self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**self.params)

        # close the communication with the PostgreSQL
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)

    def __del__(self):
        # close the communication with the PostgreSQL
        self.conn.close()
        print('Database connection closed.')
'''
    def execute(self,command):
        try:
            #TODO: figure out a squeal query to add a new record
            cur = self.conn.cursor()
            cur.excecute(command)
            out = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
            if out is None:
                return 'Nothing to Return'
            return out
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
            return None

    def add_record(self,dta_dict):
        try:
            cur = self.conn.cursor()
            cur.execute('')
            cur.close()
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
'''
 def select_all(self, table = None):
        if table is None:
            table = """electronics"""
        out = None
        try:
            cur = self.conn.cursor()
            print('cursor created')
            cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM """+table+""";""")
            print('query excecute')
            out = cur.fetchall()
            print('output read:')
            print(out)
            cur.close()
            print('cursor closed')
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
        return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db_int = Db_Interactor()
    print(db_int.select_all())
    #tickers = ts.ticker_from_csv() 
    #stonks = ts.get_stocks_from_list(tickers)
#    for i in stonks:
#        db_int.add_record(i)
```

## Instantiation and Function Call:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    db_int = Db_Interactor()
    print(db_int.select_all())
```

## Return:

```
Connecting to the PostgreSQL database... 
cursor created
query excecuted
output read:
[]
cursor closed
[]
Database connection closed.
```

## Attempts

I expected it to return my data and I don't know why. I tried switching string types (from a diff question on stack overflow) and adding ";" but nothing changed. I double checked to see if the database has data in it by running psql (as shown above) and using SELECT * FROM electronics; and the data does show.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is this Db_Integrator?  Please include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You haven't shown us how the code connects to the database, so we don't know if the `electronics` table is the same one you queried with the `psql` command.  Maybe you're connecting as a different user, and that user has its own empty table.

Comment: I have only the standard 'postgres' user with one database and one table. It's a fresh install of postgreSQL from Source Code. I have followed the steps shown here : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/install-getsource.html

Comment: Works for me.  The only way I can reproduce your python output is if table electronics exists but is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have solved it. Apparantly because I added the testing record to the database using the psql command it didn't register when I tried to access it with python but instead I just had the instantiated and empty table. Why this happened I still have no idea, but it is enough of a solution for my current project. As long as all data is fed in and out of the database using psycogn2 then everything should be work fine.